# I want to have selectbox where the user can input his data

Tags: angular

I want to customize the select box option where the user can input data and add data if the data is not available in dropdown list.

Comment: can you share more details ?? how the user will put the data by inputbox more example will be hrlpful

Comment: For mundane functionality look into HTML `datalist` tag.

Comment: I have one popup form where I am using this dropdown for booking patients if the patient is available in the dropdown list he/ she can use that name but if the name is not available user can add a new patient name in that list in the same drop-down list.

Comment: @NgBuil have you seen the solution I suggest you for your issue ?

Comment: Yes, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow !

Have you tried to create a two-way data binding variable to get the input value ?

Here is an example

**component.html**

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let food of foods; let i = index" [value]="i">
        {{food}}
    </option>
</select>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="option"> <!-- Here is your two-way data binding variable -->
<button (click)="addOption()">add</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
foods: string[] = [
    'Steak',
    'Tacos',
    'Pizza'
];

option: string = ''; // Here is your two-way data binding variable

addOption(){
    this.foods.push(this.option)
    this.option = ''
}
```

When you will write on your input text, `option` in your component will automatically be modified. So when you will click on add button it will send the `option` to `foods`.

In this case the input text isn't in the select options, and if you don't use Angular Material Components, I don't know how to insert it inside of the select dropdown but it's maybe possible.

In case you want to use Angular Material Components, you can easily add the input inside of the dropdown like bellow

**component.html**

```
<mat-select>
    <mat-option disabled>
        <input style="width:80%;" matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="option">
        <button mat-button style="width:20%;"(click)="addOption()">add</button>
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods; let i = index" [value]="i">
        {{food}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```